# How to set a variable in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

```
result=1
# more code here...
my_command_here... | awk '{
        if (/(this text exists in the stdout)/)
            result=$?
    }'
```

I'd like for result to be changed to the value of `0` (successful exit) if the stdout from the `my_command_here` includes `this text exists in the stdout`.

Everything works except the `result=$?` part. Hows does one set a variable in awk?

Comment: awk doesn't know about shell things like `$?` (and shell doesn't know about awk variables --- that is the `result` in `result=1` has nothing to do with the `result` within the awk script). Take a look at the above possible duplicate link and let us know if that helps.

Comment: @jas Ah that would explain a lot. So how could I return 0 from awk and set the result variable?

Comment: `exit 0` in the awk.  And then `result = $?` _after_ the awk.

Comment: @jas It works! Thanks. Is there any way to print something before calling the exit 0 in the awk if clause?

Comment: `if (...) { print "hello"; exit 0 }`